# React How to store HTML tags as a Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to know how to store an html tag as a Javascript object. Consider the following code:

```
const temp = () => {
    const complexity = "O(n<sup>2</sup>)"
    return (
        <div>
            {complexity}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Right now, it renders as the exact string: O(n<sup>2</sup>)
Instead I want the `<sup>` to be treated as a the html tag and render as: O(n<sup>2</sup>)

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a string in the first place, use JSX:

```
const complexity = <React.Fragment>O(n<sup>2</sup>)</React.Fragment>
```

The React.Fragment is only needed here because you have three top-level nodes (text, element, text).

Answer (score 1):

This is not working because its not HTML its jsx.
jsx must retun a single element..so just wrap your `<sup>` tag inside any other tag

```
const Test = () => {
const complexity = <span>O(n<sup>2</sup>)</span>
return (
    <div>
        {complexity}
    </div>
)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to wrap them with empty fragments instead. E.g.

```
const complexity = <>O(n<sup>2</sup>)</>
```